# Difficulty obtaining malware traffic

Tags: malware, networking, virtual-machines

I'm trying to get a particular piece of malware to beacon, and I have my box connected to remnux, with inetsim and fakedns running. Using this setup I have been able to acquire good pcap from most samples, but this one is a bit vexing.

I can see that my sample is reaching out over TCP to the correct C2 server, but ICMP returns "destination unreachable (network unreachable)". I went ahead and used route/iptables as described in this post: https://techanarchy.net/blog/installing-and-configuring-inetsim but now I'm finding it difficult to find the traffic since it's all to my IP in wireshark, and it seems to be ssl encrypted.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind.

The answer to my question is that my particular sample uses it's own custom protocol that it sends over SSL. I can't go into further detail without mentioning the particular sample family I was working on.

I didn't need to decrypt SSL traffic or anything, my previous steps actually did expose the web traffic the way I wanted it.

Also, I was wrong that my steps changed the source/destination in wireshark, it was actually fine.